# Finding total elements in a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

I have a confusion.

How many terms in the following series are needed to make a sun greater than 5/2?

```
1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5 + 1/6 + .........
```

Is there any shortcut technique to find this out?

Comment: The shortcut is that the sum from $\frac12$ up to $\frac 1n$ is approximately $\ln n$

Comment: according to this, what will be total terms needed here? @Hagen von Eitzen

Comment: $H_{n + 1} - 1 > {5 \over 2}$. I guess there isn't an analytical  expression for $n$.

Answer (score 3):

One may observe that, since $x \mapsto \dfrac1x$ is decreasing over $[2,\infty)$, one has
$$
\ln N-\ln 2=\int_2^N \frac1x\,dx\le\sum_{n=2}^N \frac1n
$$ giving that
$$
\frac52\leq\ln N-\ln 2 \implies 2\:e^{2.5}\approx 25\le N
$$ is *sufficient*.

Comment: My bad, I did not notice the OP's series starts at 1/2

Answer (score 1):

Observe that, for $k\geq 1$,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=2}^{2^k}\frac{1}{n}&=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^k}\\
&>\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^k} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2} \qquad (\textrm{k times}) \\
&=\frac{k}{2}.
\end{align*}
That is, 
$$ \sum_{n=2}^{2^k}\frac{1}{n}>\frac{k}{2} $$
Using this (crude) estimate, we need $2^5=32$ terms.